# Having fun with nyms

Tags: word, word-property

In the following sentence, can you replace every dash (-) with a character so that the sentence makes logical sense?

An ----nym is an ----nym of an ---nym.

Comment: Frick I'm stupid. Disregard my answer >_<

Comment: If the middle word had "a" instead of "an", I'd say that any -nym is a [paronym](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paronym) of any other -nym. (Is it the same as oAlt's deleted answer?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is...

> An **autonym** is an **antonym** of an **exonym**.

Meanings:

> **Autonym**: A name by which a people or social group refers to itself. ([source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/autonym))

> **Antonym**: A word having a meaning opposite to that of another word. ([source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/antonym))

> **Exonym**: A name by which one people or social group refers to another and by which the group so named does not refer to itself. ([source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exonym))

Comment: That's it - you got it! The first word can be replaced with rot13(raqbalz)

Comment: You are solving all my puzzles!

Comment: That's a pure coincidence :)

Comment: Congrats on 1K reputation. Very impressive for just two weeks!